# Non Impactful, yet annoying error in Visual Studio 2019 16.4.5 involving Microsoft::WRL

Tags: c++

I've just updated to VS 16.4.5, and am seeing an error across all the projects I have that use Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr:

> E0135: class Microsoft::WRL::Details::EnableIf<false, void> has no member "type"

Has anyone seen a similar thing happening to them? I've tried to find a way to disable that error using a pragma directive or something but have had no luck on google. Anyone got any ideas?

The error has had no impact on the building/execution of my code, but it is a bit of a nuisance.

Comment: What about `#pragma warning(disable:E0135)`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=vs-2019  Or have you already tried that?

Comment: Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to tell them about IntelliSense parser bugs.